# How to underline MenuItem.Header property during mouse over?

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I have a standard Menu with a couple of toplevel MenuItems + children. The controltemplate looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="{x:Type Menu}" TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource LinkTextColorBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
                    <Border BorderThickness="0">
                        <StackPanel ClipToBounds="True" Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border x:Name="Border">
            <Grid>
                <ContentPresenter Margin="6,3,6,3"  ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                <Popup x:Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Fade">
                    <Border x:Name="SubmenuBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" BorderThickness="1" Background="GhostWhite">
                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush  Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource CstBorderLightGrey}, Path=Color}" />
                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Popup" Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource HotLinkTextColorBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,4,4" />
                <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,3" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelItemTemplateKey}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border x:Name="Border">
            <Grid>
                <ContentPresenter Margin="6,3,6,3" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                <Popup x:Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Fade">
                    <Border x:Name="SubmenuBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" BorderThickness="1" Background="GhostWhite">
                        <Border.BorderBrush>

                            <SolidColorBrush  Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource CstBorderLightGrey}, Path=Color}" />
                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Popup" Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource HotLinkTextColorBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,4,4" />
                <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,3" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

There are some minor adjustments left but apart from that it works fine. But i'm having one problem, I need to make the toplevelitems underlined during mouseover. I've been searching for information about this for a long time and i've come up with nothing so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the `MenuItem.Header` property to add a `TextBlock` with an underline to the menu item header section:

```
<MenuItem>
    <MenuItem.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding YourHeaderProperty}" TextDecorations="Underline" />
    </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

It's worth pointing out that you *may* confuse your users when you do this, because underlined text *usually* means that it is a hyper link.

---

UPDATE >>>

You just need to rearrange the code a little and add a `DataTrigger` to make the change:

```
<MenuItem>
    <MenuItem.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="rtuwruhey5uje5yu">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="None" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={
                            RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}}" 
                            Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: I am terribly sorry but i forgot to write that it should only be underlined during mouseover. I also would like the styling to be done in the controltemplate if possible. i will change my description.

Comment: Yeah, it often helps to know what the question author wants *before* I write an answer.

Comment: Is it possible to add that somehow to the resourcedictionary that i included in my question?

Comment: You'd have to use a `DataTemplate` for the `MenuItem.HeaderTemplate` property to define the `TextBlock` in the example, but yes, it is possible.